# can you explain why my class will not return to main program?

Tags: java

so the assignment I have is as follows.

The challenge...
The program is supposed to ask for the number of units sold and compute the total cost of the purchase.
I am also supposed to include a input validation so that the number of units is greater than 0.
Package price is $99, Quantity discounts are:
10-19 20%
20-49 30%
50-99 40%
100 or more 50%

I have my class demo that I have to use to test my code,

```
    package Chapter4;
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class SoftwareSalesDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int units; // To hold units sold

    // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Get the units sold.
    System.out.print("Enter the units sold: ");
    units = keyboard.nextInt();

    // Create a SoftwareSales object.
    SoftwareSales sales = new SoftwareSales(units);

    // Display purchase info.
    DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
    System.out.println("Units sold: " + sales.getUnitsSold());
    System.out.println("Discount: $" + dollar.format(sales.getDiscount()));
    System.out.println("Cost: $" + dollar.format(sales.getCost()));

}

}
```

The following is the class that I wrote this is what I need help with.

```
package Chapter4;

/*
 * Software sales class
 * 
 * Eric Goldberg
 * 
 * Calculate the total cost of units sold */

public class SoftwareSales {

//fields 
private int UnitsSold;
private double Discount;
private double Cost;
private double UnitCost=99.00;


public SoftwareSales (int uni) 
{
    UnitsSold = uni;

}



public Discount(double dis)
{
    Discount = dis;

    if(UnitsSold >=10 && UnitsSold<=19) {
        Discount = .20;
    }

    if(UnitsSold >= 20 && UnitsSold<=49) {
        Discount = .30;
    }

    if (UnitsSold >= 50 && UnitsSold <= 99) {
        Discount = .40;
    }

    if (UnitsSold >= 100) {
        Discount = .50;
    }

} //end of discount

public double UnitCost() {
    return UnitCost=99.00;
}

public  void setCost(double cost) {
    Cost = Discount*UnitsSold;
}

//return the discount amount. 
public double getDiscount() 
{
    return Discount;
}

//return unitssold. 
public int getUnitsSold() {
    return UnitsSold;
}

//return cost
public double getCost() {
    return Cost;
}

}
```

Comment: What's the exact problem?

Comment: Your code shouldn't compile because `public Discount(double dis)` is a constructor not in a Discount class

Comment: A lot of your methods are never called. Also this `Cost = Discount*UnitsSold` does not look correct.

Comment: You call `getCost()` but never `setCost()`.

Comment: And read about Java naming conventions. Variable names go camelCase.

Comment: @Goldbeed - did you try my solution? If it worked then please accept the answer and vote up!

Comment: you came here last year asking for help and received what looks to me being a solution. The answer should be accepted and mark the question as solved. So, where are you in all of this? You haven't breathed a word in regards to comments or the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct the cost and discount calculation. I am assuming you need total cost and total discount. You can make input (no of units) validation as fancy as you want. (like read string and then parseInt). For now, i am assuming that input will be an integer and until user enters integer >0, i keep on asking.

SoftwareSalesDemo.java

```
package Chapter4;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SoftwareSalesDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // To hold units sold
        int units;

        // Display purchase info.
        DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

        // Get the units sold.
        System.out.print("Enter the units sold: ");

        // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        units = keyboard.nextInt();

        while (units <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Please enter valid no. of units (>0)");
            units = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
        // Create a SoftwareSales object.
        SoftwareSales sales = new SoftwareSales(units);
        System.out.println("Units sold     : " + sales.getUnitsSold());
        System.out.println("Total Discount : $" + dollar.format(sales.getDiscount()));
        System.out.println("Total Cost     : $" + dollar.format(sales.getCost()));

    }
}
```

SoftwareSales.java

```
package Chapter4;

/*
 * Software sales class
 * 
 * Eric Goldberg
 * 
 * Calculate the total cost of units sold */

public class SoftwareSales {

    // fields
    private int unitsSold;
    private double discount;
    private double cost;
    private double unitCost = 99.00;

    public SoftwareSales(int units) {
        this.unitsSold = units;
        setDiscount();
        setCost();
    }

    // set discount based on no. of units sold
    private void setDiscount() {
        if (unitsSold >= 10 && unitsSold <= 19) {
            discount = .20;
        }

        if (unitsSold >= 20 && unitsSold <= 49) {
            discount = .30;
        }

        if (unitsSold >= 50 && unitsSold <= 99) {
            discount = .40;
        }

        if (unitsSold >= 100) {
            discount = .50;
        }
    } // end of discount

    // return per unit cost
    private double getUnitCost() {
        return unitCost;
    }

    // calculate total cost
    private void setCost() {
        cost = unitsSold * (getUnitCost() * (1 - discount));
    }

    // return the discount amount.
    public double getDiscount() {
        return ((discount * getUnitCost()) * unitsSold);
    }

    // return unitsSold.
    public int getUnitsSold() {
        return unitsSold;
    }

    // return total cost
    public double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }
}
```

Sample Runs

```
Enter the units sold: 10
Units sold     : 10
Total Discount : $198.00
Total Cost     : $792.00

Enter the units sold: 50
Units sold     : 50
Total Discount : $1,980.00
Total Cost     : $2,970.00

Enter the units sold: 100
Units sold     : 100
Total Discount : $4,950.00
Total Cost     : $4,950.00
```

Comment: Do you really think, giving a complete answer is the best way to help somebody to learn programming?

Comment: My bad, intention was to give solution and show the missing pieces. Probably next time would just provide hints.